# Android Libs Blurry Not Working

Tags: android, blur, blurry

I use  https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry library.

in `Onclick`, the following code works.

```
private boolean blurred = false;

if (blurred) {
      Blurry.delete((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content));
    } else {
      long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Blurry.with(MainActivity.this)
          .radius(25)
          .sampling(2)
          .async()
          .animate(500)
          .onto((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content));
    }
blurred = !blurred;
```

But when I add the following code in `OnCreate`, it doesn't work.

```
Blurry.with(MainActivity.this)
      .radius(25)
      .sampling(2)
      .async()
      .animate(500)
      .onto((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content));
```

Comment: show your oncreate() please . Not working means Crashing ?

Comment: My OnCreate only :
 Blurry.with(MainActivity.this)
          .radius(25)
          .sampling(2)
          .async()
          .animate(500)
          .onto((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content));

Comment: What device are you running this on? @ThangBA

Comment: My device is Sony C6603 Android 4.4.2 API 19

Comment: Could you call this out of `onCreate()` scope. Could be place this into some callback function of button-click. I'm afraid your view is not ready for blurring yet.

Comment: I thinks too. Can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your library uses [view size](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry/blob/master/blurry/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/blurry/Blurry.java#L104)

```
  factor.width = target.getMeasuredWidth();
  factor.height = target.getMeasuredHeight();
```

When you call it. In `onCreate` your view has not created. you should move it for example to `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` or use any suggestion from answer of `for3st` by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0)